# how to define ENTER in textarea while sending mail using php

Tags: php, html, email

I have a form that is sending as mail in php.
i wanna define ENTER key in textarea content as breakline while sending it.
when i type something like this :

> hi
>
> how are you?

in the inbox it shows as :

> hi how are you?

please help me to fix it!

my HTML code :

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="from">
<input type="text" name="to">
<textarea name="content" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>
</form>
```

my PHP code :

```
$to  = $_POST['to'] ;
$subject = $_POST['from'];
$message = $_POST['content'];
mail($to, $subject, $message, //$headers);
```

Comment: You don't really need to do anything special. You could normalise line feeds but I don't think it's strictly necessary. Is it possible that your mail client displays plain text messages wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you are setting the text/html content type in your headers. Try using plain text or convert the `\n` to `<br>`

Comment: Is the PHP code your real code?

Comment: no its not complete code

Answer (score -1):

oops! someone answered my question but now his post is deleted!

it worked as:

```
$message=nl2br($_POST['content']);
```

Comment: Email is plain text by default. Since we aren't setting any `Content-Type: text/html` header, HTML tags will show up as-is.